# Pass variable from directive to controller (with ControllerAs vm syntax)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I've recently read a bunch of AngularJS styleguides and best practices and I ended up [using this boilerplate code](https://github.com/jakemmarsh/angularjs-gulp-browserify-boilerplate) for creating a project with Angular, Gulp and Browserify.

The aforementioned boilerplate uses a multitude of best practices, from folder structure and bundling with browserify, to certain [angularJS guidelines](https://github.com/toddmotto/angularjs-styleguide#controllers)

I created a simple attribute directive (my first ever), that would get the $window.width and it would set a certain variable on the scope, depending on the window width.
The reason is that I have an image grid, and I would like to conditionally limit the total amount of displayed pictures, depending on screen width. Essentially the value would be used in a limitTo filter in the ngRepeat that renders all pictures.

So for example you could get a grid of 6 pictures on a mobile, 8 pictures on a tablet, and 12 on desktop.

The problem is that the controller uses ControllerAs vm syntax, therefore I need to inject the $scope in it, which according to the aforementioned styleguide is a bad practice and should be used only when absolutely necessary (e.g. publishing and subscribing to events)

As i'm fairly new both to writing my own directives, and the controllerAs vm syntax I have no idea how to proceed. If I'm not supposed to inject the scope in the controller how can I access the variable coming from the directive?

[Code snippets of the custom directive and my controller](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/faf9b206b8fed794164f)

Comment: I'm using Angular 1.3.11

Answer (score 1):

So, basically you want to avoid using scope and use controller in html.

I have created plnkr example - extending your code. http://plnkr.co/edit/YOd3KlzTpVviLVuoEBfN?p=preview

In this example, I showed how to define a function on controller and invoke it from html and accessing its properties in html. This is all done without using `$scope`.

here is a complete snippet

**html**

```
  <div break-limit>
    <p>Title: {{ctrl.title}}</p>
    <p>Number: {{ctrl.number}}</p>
    Limit : {{ctrl.limit}}
    <br>
    <br>
    <input ng-model="ctrl.name"/> 
    <button ng-click="ctrl.sayHello()">Say Hello</button>
  </div>
```

**.js**

```
   (function() {
  var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

  function ExampleCtrl() {
    var vm = this;

    vm.title = 'AngularJS, using ControllerAs in Directive!';
    vm.number = 1234;
    vm.name = "CASE";

  }

  angular.extend(ExampleCtrl.prototype, {
    sayHello: function() {
      alert('Hello, ' + this.name);
    }
  });

  function breakLimit($window) {
    return {
      controller: ExampleCtrl,
      scope: true,
      controllerAs: 'ctrl',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
        var width = $window.innerWidth;
        if (width <= 640) {
          ctrl.limit = 6;
        }
        if (641 <= width <= 1024) {
          ctrl.limit = 8;
        }
        if (1025 <= width <= 1440) {
          ctrl.limit = 12;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  app.directive('breakLimit', breakLimit);
})();
```

Comment: Interesting solution, but I was wondering if this solution is reusable and not strictly tied to the 'ExampleCtrl'. Is there a way that I could pass the controller/controllerAs in the directive from my HTML, so that I could use it with other controllers as well?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want to achieve here.
Sharing controller across multiple directives is not a good idea as long as they are not related. You should use service for that. 
you can refer following link to learn how to establish this communication
https://github.com/ynmanware/AngTest/tree/master/Angular-unrelated-controller-messaging

I pasted one refined example to plnkr
http://plnkr.co/edit/den1mfMeIAWezLTuVZVX?p=preview

**html**

```
 <body>
   <div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="Controller1 as ctrl">
        <br> 
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><B> Enter Description in Controller1</B></td>
                <td><input type="text" ng-model="ctrl.description"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div ng-controller="Controller2 as ctrl">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><B> Description in controller2</B></td>
                <td>{{ctrl.description}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
  </body>
```

**.js**

```
(function(app) {

    function SharedService() {
        var description = "Master";
    }

    angular.extend(SharedService.prototype, {
        getDescription: function() {
            return this.description;
        },
        setDescription: function(desc) {
            this.description = desc;
        }
    });

    function Controller1(SharedService) {
        this.sharedService = SharedService;
    }

    Object.defineProperty(Controller1.prototype,
        'description', {
            enumerable: true, //indicate that it supports enumerations
            configurable: false, //disable delete operation
            get: function() {
                return this.sharedService.getDescription();
            },
            set: function(val) {
                this.sharedService.setDescription(val);
            }
        });

    function Controller2(SharedService) {
        this.sharedService = SharedService;
    }

    Object.defineProperty(Controller2.prototype,
        'description', { //read only property
            enumerable: true,
            configurable: false,
            get: function() {
                return this.sharedService.getDescription();
            }
        });

    app.service('SharedService', SharedService);
    app.controller('Controller1', Controller1);
    app.controller('Controller2', Controller2);

})(angular.module('myApp', []));
```